# setVisible(false) to a group of JTextField and JLabel

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jlabel, jtextfield

I have a group of `JTextField` and `JLabel`. I want them to initially not be visible so I thought to initialize my applet with a method which calls `setVisible(false)` for each of the components.

Is it possible to create a method `setVisible(false)` which will set the visibility of all the components to false. Finally if I have 40 components in the applet, is it possible to do this with only one command instead of 40 commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your buttons and labels to a JPanel and then you can simply make your JPanel invisible to hide them all with one call.

```
jPanel.setVisible(false);
```

**Alternatively**, add your buttons and labels to a JComponent list, and then loop through it:

```
List<JComponent> list = new ArrayList<JComponent>();
list.add(button);
list.add(label);
for(JComponent c : list){
    c.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: I'm building a japplet so each jbutton, jlabels etc.. declaration is not editable... any ideas?
Anyway it's an excellent suggestion, thank you