# Call textfield object with its name and set some properties

Tags: java, swing

I have Vector named "datas". Vector looks like;

[1000, 3, 676767, true]

And i have jTextField named "p3_1000"

I write below code for set this text field as invisible or visible.

```
for(int i = 0; i<= datas.size(); i++){

     if(datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(3).equals("true")){

      ???

     }

System.out.println("p"+(datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(1))+"_"+(datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(0)));
}
```

Print Line show correct format "p3_1000" as like my textfield name. But i dont find a ways set releated textfield call with its name. How i write this code for automaticly detect true textfield ?

I must say if 3th index of current vector row is "true" set visible textfield named "p"+(datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(1))+"_"+(datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(0))

But how?

Can we call any object with its name using any string referance ?

Comment: you can put a name to your textfield with this method `setName`

Comment: @nachokk i have already named 100 textfield. 1 and 0 index element of Each vector rows equal my textfields as you can see. I just call releated text field when i loop vector rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(3)=="true"` doesn't work as you expect in Java. `==` is used to compare the equivalence of two objects, and what you have here are two different objects.

You're looking for `datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(3).equals("true")` which compares the contents of the strings.

If you're looking for the code to make a text field visible or invisible, use `setVisible(true)` or `setVisible(false)` - see also this post: [setVisible(false) to a group of JTextField and JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168030/setvisiblefalse-to-a-group-of-jtextfield-and-jlabel)

Finally, for the part where you're trying to use string composition to determine the name of an instance of a JTextField - I would suggest that there is a better approach. Maintain a HashMap where the string that you compose is the key to the map, and you can always get the corresponding text field by doing `map.get(key)` instead of trying to create the name of the variable... which would require reflection, and that's not a path you need to go down.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for in the ??? line - are you asking for the code that makes the text field visible?

Comment: Yes i want make named "p3_1000" text field as visible. But i dont use p3_1000.set... command. Because i have many textfield and true textfield detect from datas vector like in print line control.

Comment: p3_1000.setVisible(true); working i know. But releated textfield name must be detect from Vector releated values. like "p"+(datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(1))+"_"+(datas.elementAt(i).elementAt(0))

Comment: I cant use group. Because i have 100 textfield and each textfield must be controlled one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the HashMap advice. I dont use it before and concentrate on it with your advice. I find [THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958600/get-a-swing-component-by-name) about call components by their names. It solve my problem completely. Thanks for all.